# How to find all the possible sequence of elements in 1-D array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

For example,I have an 1-D array a={1,2,3},how can I find all the possible sequences of the elements in that array?
like,I need
{1 2 3},{1 3 2},{2 1 3},{2 3 1},{3 1 2},{3 2 1},how to implement it in java?

Comment: I would suggest you think about it for a little while, come up with an algorithm and translate that algorithm in Java code. If you encounter a **specific** problem during that process, ask the according question here.

Comment: start by talking it out... how would you (a human) accomplish this on paper? Then, break each step you took down into the smallest pieces possible. Then translate that into pseudo code. Then translate that into java code.

Comment: I see,I will try to think it more deeper.Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

To genereate the possible combinations of array elements, you need to use [Permutations](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/Permutations.java.html).